# CSS: Divs don't line up left and right

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have 2 divs. I want 1 div to be on the left side of my window and the other on the right side. I did this correctly with my logo and a little text next to it. However, under that I would like to have yet another 2 divs. I put those 2 divs in 1 div with style `clear:both;` this div lines up nicely under the two others. But once I do `float: right;` with the 2nd div, it goes outside the main div... Why?

The code:
(This should be lined up to the left)

```
#menu {
    background-color:#485D9C;
    margin-left:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
}
```

(This should be lined up to the right)

```
#content {
    text-align:right;
    width:600px;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
}
```

(This is the div where both "content" and "menu" are in)

```
#middle {
    clear:both;
    border: thick solid;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: What is your current HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an example ? With this little test: http://jsfiddle.net/BouFe/uHJQB/1/ it works !

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: Sry, i don't have access to post comment yet ;-) began today !

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I am using floats, I put a div, with "clear: both;" applied to it, inside of the container that holds the elements that have the float applied to them. An example of this can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sN7eA/), which I *think* is what you were looking for.

Comment: No problem. Selecting my answer by clicking the check to the left would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

try placing an outer div and set the position: relative; and the inner elements mark their position as absolute

Comment: This worked somewhat for me. I did what you said and both my divs are inside my main div, except there is one little problem. The right div is over the left one. Even with a float: right; it doesn't want to move to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what's going on without seeing your code, but I'm wondering if you're simply just no clearing your floats?

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html